# Unpack variadic template to initializer_list and call two functions at once

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, initializer-list, argument-unpacking

I have two vectors:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v1{ 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<int> v2{ 4, 5, 6 };
```

I want to create an object of `std::initializer_list` which holds iterators to the first and last elements of above vectors.

I want to have a function with a variadic template:

```cpp
template<class... Ts>
void foo(Ts... args)
```

and inside above function I want to unpack all arguments. So far I implemented:

```cpp
template<class... Ts>
void foo(Ts... args)
{
  std::initializer_list<std::vector<int>::iterator> il{
    (std::begin(args), std::end(args))...
  };
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v1{ 1, 2, 3 };
  std::vector<int> v2{ 4, 5, 6 };

  foo(v1, v2);
}
```

but it doesn't work as expected due to `operator,`. Current implementation creates `initializer_list` with two iterators. What I want in this case is to have an `initializer_list` with 4 iterators pointing to the first and one past the end element of these two vectors. I want it to be `begin`, `end`, `begin`, `end`.

Comment: Do you need them to be interleaved, `begin, end, begin, end` - or would `begin, begin, end, end` work?

Comment: begin, end, begin, end.

Comment: BTW, your signature is strange, Ts would be any type whereas you only expect `std::vector<int>`, taking `std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int>>>` might be more appropriate.

Comment: The problem is more complicated than you think. For simplicity of the question I modified my source code. The answers I received resolve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a new pack which is double the length:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

namespace detail {

template<std::size_t... I, class... Ts>
void foo_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>, Ts&... args) {
    std::initializer_list<std::vector<int>::iterator> il{
        [&]() -> std::vector<int>::iterator {
            auto& vec = std::get<I/2u>(std::tie(args...));
            return I % 2u == 0u ? std::begin(vec) : std::end(vec);
        }()...
    };

    // ...
}

}

template<class... Ts>
void foo(Ts... args) {
    return detail::foo_impl(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(args)*2u>{}, args...);
}
```

Or consider if you need an `initializer_list` at all. You might be able to use an array:

```cpp
template<class... Ts>
void foo(Ts... args) {
    std::vector<int>::iterator il[sizeof...(args)*2u];
    {
        auto* p = std::begin(il);
        (((*p++ = std::begin(args)), (*p++ = std::end(args))), ...);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You might create array instead of `initializer_list`:

```
template<class... Ts>
auto foo(Ts&... args)
{
    std::array<typename std::common_type_t<std::decay_t<Ts>...>::iterator, 2 * sizeof...(Ts)> res;

    std::size_t i = 0;
    ((res[i++] = args.begin(), res[i++] = args.end()), ...);

    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xGYKWcbr4)

Answer (score 4):

I think your best bet is to add the iterators in forms of `std::pair`s:

```cpp
template<class... Ts>
void foo(Ts... args) {
    std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::vector<int>::iterator,
                                    std::vector<int>::iterator>> il
    {
        {std::begin(args), std::end(args)}...
    };
}
```

This `initializer_list` would now have two `std::pair`s with `begin()` and `end()` iterators, that is, 4 iterators in total.

Comment: That is a great answer, but unfortunately I cannot have `std::pair` in my `std::initializer_list`. Is it possible to do it without nested types inside `std::initializer_list`?

Comment: @RagdollCar Hmm, I will need to give that a think :-)